# Go http, send incoming http.request to an other server using client.Do

Tags: go

Here my use case

We have one services "foobar"  which has two version `legacy`  and `version_2_of_doom`   (both in go)

In order to make the transition from `legacy` to `version_2_of_doom` , we would like in a first time, to have the  two version alongside, and have the POST request (as there's only one  POST api call in this ) received on both.

The way I see how to do it. Would be

1. modifying the code of `legacy`  at the beginning of the handler, in order to duplicate the request to `version_2_of_doom`

   ```
    func(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
        req.URL.Host = "v2ofdoom.local:8081"
        req.Host = "v2ofdoom.local:8081"
        client := &http.Client{}
        client.Do(req)
        // legacy code
   ```

but it seems to not be as straightforward as this

it fails with  `http: Request.RequestURI can't be set in client requests.`

Is there a well-known method to do this kind of action (i.e transfering without touching) a `http.Request` to an other server ?

Comment: You don't need to create a new `http.Client` for every request, they are intended to be use multiple times.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to copy the values you want into a new request. Since this is very similar to what a reverse proxy does, you may want to look at what ["net/http/httputil"](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/) does for `ReverseProxy`.

Create a new request, and copy only the parts of the request you want to send to the next server. You will also need to read and buffer the request body if you intend to use it both places:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    // we need to buffer the body if we want to read it here and send it
    // in the request. 
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // you can reassign the body if you need to parse it as multipart
    req.Body = ioutil.NopCloser(bytes.NewReader(body))

    // create a new url from the raw RequestURI sent by the client
    url := fmt.Sprintf("%s://%s%s", proxyScheme, proxyHost, req.RequestURI)

    proxyReq, err := http.NewRequest(req.Method, url, bytes.NewReader(body))

    // We may want to filter some headers, otherwise we could just use a shallow copy
    // proxyReq.Header = req.Header
    proxyReq.Header = make(http.Header)
    for h, val := range req.Header {
        proxyReq.Header[h] = val
    }

    resp, err := httpClient.Do(proxyReq)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusBadGateway)
        return
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    // legacy code
}
```

Comment: I needed to define  `httpClient := http.Client{}` , proxyscheme and proxyhost, but yoursolutions seems to work , thanks

Comment: It appears that for Go 1.13 (which will be released next month I believe) this should be relatively simplified. You should be able to call `req.Clone(<context>)` and get back a cloned `*http.Request` with it's context set to the context of your choosing. https://go-review.googlesource.com/c/go/+/174324/

Answer (score 12):

In my experience, the easiest way to achieve this was to simply create a new request and copy all request attributes that you need into the new request object:

```
func(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    url := req.URL
    url.Host = "v2ofdoom.local:8081"

    proxyReq, err := http.NewRequest(req.Method, url.String(), req.Body)
    if err != nil {
        // handle error
    }

    proxyReq.Header.Set("Host", req.Host)
    proxyReq.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-For", req.RemoteAddr)

    for header, values := range req.Header {
        for _, value := range values {
            proxyReq.Header.Add(header, value)
        }
    }

    client := &http.Client{}
    proxyRes, err := client.Do(proxyReq)

    // and so on...
```

This approach has the benefit of not modifying the original request object (maybe your handler function or any middleware functions that are living in your stack still need the original object?).

Comment: thanks for your answer, it seems to have some compilation error `$http.Client{}` the `$`,   and   http.NewRequest seems to require a string not a URL object

Comment: I also needed to add `url.Scheme = "http"`

Comment: and I don't know if it's needed, but replacing the double for loop by  `proxyReq.Header = req.Header` seems to work

Comment: As long as you're not modifying the headers, that's fine. If you want to pass different headers to the other service (note I'm adding a `X-Forwarded-For` header, in my example), it's usually better to actually copy the headers.

Comment: There's a Header.Clone() method so no need to loop ourselves. Also copy headers to the `w` response via the sample loop over `proxyRes` proxy response like `w.Header().Add(header, value)` if forwarding a request

Answer (score 3):

Using original request (copy or duplicate only if original request still need):

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    // Step 1: rewrite URL
    URL, _ := url.Parse("https://full_generic_url:123/x/y")
    r.URL.Scheme = URL.Scheme
    r.URL.Host = URL.Host
    r.URL.Path = singleJoiningSlash(URL.Path, r.URL.Path)
    r.RequestURI = ""

    // Step 2: adjust Header
    r.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-For", r.RemoteAddr)

    // note: client should be created outside the current handler()
    client := &http.Client{} 
    // Step 3: execute request
    resp, err := client.Do(r)
    if err != nil {
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return
    }

    // Step 4: copy payload to response writer
    copyHeader(w.Header(), resp.Header)
    w.WriteHeader(resp.StatusCode)
    io.Copy(w, resp.Body)
    resp.Body.Close()
}

// copyHeader and singleJoiningSlash are copy from "/net/http/httputil/reverseproxy.go"
func copyHeader(dst, src http.Header) {
    for k, vv := range src {
        for _, v := range vv {
            dst.Add(k, v)
        }
    }
}

func singleJoiningSlash(a, b string) string {
    aslash := strings.HasSuffix(a, "/")
    bslash := strings.HasPrefix(b, "/")
    switch {
    case aslash && bslash:
        return a + b[1:]
    case !aslash && !bslash:
        return a + "/" + b
    }
    return a + b
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I've seen the accepted anwser, but I would like to say that I dont like this. I've used this code for months with it working, but after some time you encounter requests that break (`POST` requests in my case). My preferred solution is the following:

```
r.URL.Host = "example.com"
r.RequestURI = ""
client := &http.Client{}

delete(r.Header, "Accept-Encoding")
delete(r.Headers, "Content-Length")
resp, err := client.Do(r.WithContext(context.Background())
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
return resp, nil
```