# Golang ReverseProxy with Apache2 SNI/Hostname error

Tags: ssl, go, apache2, reverse-proxy, sni

i am writing my own ReverseProxy in Go.The ReverseProxy should connect my go-webserver and my apache2 webserver. But when I run my reverseproxy on another IP-Adress then my Apache2 webserver I got following error in my apache-logfile, when the reverseproxy sends the request to apache.

```
"Hosname xxxx provided via sni and hostname xxxx2 provided via http are different"
```

My Reverse Proxy and apache-webserver running on https.

Here some code:

```
func (p *Proxy) directorApache(req *http.Request) {
    mainServer := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.HostMain, Config.PortMain)
    req.URL.Scheme = "https"
    req.URL.Host = mainServer
}

func (p *Proxy) directorGo(req *http.Request) {
    goServer := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.GoHost, Config.GoPort)
    req.URL.Scheme = "http"
    req.URL.Host = goServer
}


func (p *Proxy) ServeHTTP(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println(req.URL.Path)
    if p.isGoRequest(req) {
        fmt.Println("GO")
        p.goProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
        return
    }
    p.httpProxy.ServeHTTP(rw, req)
}
func main() {

    var configPath = flag.String("conf", "./configReverse.json", "Path to the Json config file.")

    flag.Parse()
    proxy := New(*configPath)
    cert, err := tls.LoadX509KeyPair(Config.PathCert, Config.PathPrivateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: loadkeys: %s", err)
    }
    config := tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true, Certificates: []tls.Certificate{cert}}

    listener, err := net.Listen("tcp",
    net.JoinHostPort(proxy.Host, strconv.Itoa(proxy.Port)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("server: listen: %s", err)
    }
    log.Printf("server: listening on %s")
    proxy.listener = tls.NewListener(listener, &config)

    serverHTTPS := &http.Server{
        Handler:   proxy.mux,
        TLSConfig: &config,
    }

    if err := serverHTTPS.Serve(proxy.listener); err != nil {
        log.Fatal("SERVER ERROR:", err)
    }
}
```

Perhaps someone has a idea about that issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Short example

Say you're starting an HTTP request to `https://your-proxy.local`. Your request handler takes the `http.Request` struct and rewrites its `URL` field to `https://your-apache-backend.local`.

What you have not considered, is that the original HTTP request also contained a `Host` header (`Host: your-proxy.local`). When passing that same request to `http://your-apache-backend.local`, the `Host` header in that request still says `Host: your-proxy.local`. And that's what Apache is complaining about.

#### Explanation

As you're using TLS with Server Name Indication (SNI), the request hostname will not only be used for DNS resolution, but also to select the SSL certificate that should be used to establish the TLS connection. The HTTP 1.1 `Host` header on the other hand is used to distinguish several virtual hosts by Apache. Both names **must match**. This issue is also mentioned in the [Apache HTTPD wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI):

> **SNI/Request hostname mismatch, or SNI provides hostname and request doesn't.**
>
> This is a browser bug. Apache will reject the request with a 400-type error.

#### Solution

Also rewrite the `Host` header. If you want to preserve the original `Host` header, you can store it in an `X-Forwarded-Host` header (that's a non-standard header, but it's widely used in reverse proxies):

```
func (p *Proxy) directorApache(req *http.Request) {
    mainServer := fmt.Sprintf("%s:%d", Config.HostMain, Config.PortMain)
    req.URL.Scheme = "https"
    req.URL.Host = mainServer
    req.Header.Set("X-Forwarded-Host", req.Header().Get("Host"))
    req.Host = mainServer
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your good idea and solution. You're right I didn't thought about that. But I Have a problem with that. First of all my req.Header doesn't had a Host field at all. I added the x-forwarded host manually. But setting only the Host-Header didn't solved it, i got the same error. So I tried to Set req.Host directly. Then the Apache Error is solved, but my site doesn't load anything else, i think my php on apache have then a error. I think there is then a problem with the request because i changed the host?

Comment: So I think it solved the Problem. But you have to use req.Host = mainServer because the request header will not used think it belongs to that issue here : 
 
Think have something to do with that: http://github.com/golang/go/issues/7682
The Problem i mentioned in the comment before is my AngularJS because of insecure ressource loading because my reverseproxy runs on a different ip than my angularjs.
https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$sce/insecurl
Tank you @helmbert. You made my day :)

Comment: Happy to help. I've also updated my answer to reflect the `req.Host = mainServer` change.

Comment: Think had another Problem, i didn't get any new Requests on my ReverseProxy when i change req.Host. Perhaps because the Host to send response or new requests is wrong now? I don't now. I mean the apache problem is solved but now my reverseProxy doesn't work how he should. He serves my website from apache but he doesn't get a new request, when the user do something on it.

Comment: Might be worth a new question, if it's a different issue. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724160/go-http-send-incoming-http-request-to-an-other-server-using-client-do) will also help you.