# How to forward a request in golang

Tags: go, httprequest

I have two instances of same server. Let's say these are **server1** and **server2** . They are in same machine with the same IP but the port is different.

If a request comes to **server1**, I would like to forward that request in **server2** . Please note that, I do not want a reverse proxy or something similar, I just want simply forward the request to **server2** and **server1** will basically do nothing.

This is what I have tried.
I was able to extract the request object

```
    log.Print(c.Request)
    c.Request.URL.Host = "10.0.0.100:8788"
    c.Request.Host = "10.0.0.100:8788"
    client := &http.Client{}
    client.Do(c.Request)
```

Here **10.0.0.100:8788** is the IP of **server2**

Comment: It would help to show some code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Go http, send incoming http.request to an other server using client.Do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724160/go-http-send-incoming-http-request-to-an-other-server-using-client-do)

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/httputil/#ReverseProxy

Comment: @Marc no , They have implemented reverse proxy , that's not what I want . server1 will do nothing , not even displaying anything . This will simply forward request

Comment: So, reverse proxy and drop the response?

Comment: You can either proxy the request, or reply with a redirect so the client goes and talks to `server2`. If you don't, the client will never get an answer. If you don't care about the answer, just do the new request in a separate goroutine and reply with OK and empty body.

Comment: @zerkms actually I am not sure.

Comment: @Marc could you kindly show me an example , actually I am kind of new in this stuff

Comment: Take the code from the first answer in the linked question, but send an empty response back. If you need to, you can run the request to `server2` in a separate goroutine.

Comment: Why not send a 302 redirect?

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg can u give me an example , how can I do that in go ?

Comment: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Redirect