# golang post file to flask server

Tags: go, flask

I try to create app which will send file from the form on page to the golang server and it will resend it to flask server.

My golang server:

```
func api_upload_model(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    r.ParseMultipartForm(50 << 20)
    file, handler, err := r.FormFile("Model")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Retrieving the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("Uploaded File: %+v\n", handler.Filename)
    fmt.Printf("File Size: %+v\n", handler.Size)
    
    resp, err := http.Post(*URL here*, "multipart/form-data", file)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Sending the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html")
    buffer, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    _, err = w.Write(buffer)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error Sending the File")
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
}

func main() {
    router := chi.NewRouter()
    router.Post("/api/upload_model", api_upload_model)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", router)
}
```

Flask handler:

```
@app.route('/upload_model', methods=['POST'])
def upload_model():
    log("Inference server", "123")
    name = request.args.get('name', None)
    if name is None:
        return "Error: bad request parameters."
    print(str(request))
    if 'file' not in request.files: #I know that I don't set filename to 'file' but request.files is empty anyway
        return "No file"
    file = request.files['file']
    if file:
        filename = secure_filename(name)
        file.save(os.path.join("data/models", name))
        return "200"
```

What I get from flask server:

```
<Request 'http://*URL here*/upload_model?name=1.jpg' [POST]>:
```

I tried to print request.files: it is empty.
So, golang server doesn't send file or flask server doesn't get it.

Golang prints

```
Uploaded File: 1.jpg
File Size: 114940
```

So it recieves file.

UPD:
Found this answer: [How to redirect multipart POST request to a second server in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66591844/how-to-redirect-multipart-post-request-to-a-second-server-in-golang)
and made my golang server like there. Now it doesn't parse files but sends whole request to flask server unedited. And it is more easy.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot directly pass the `FormFile` as an input to the post method instead you need to create a multipart object that contains the file.

See example
[How to use multipart in golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58105449/how-to-use-multipart-in-golang#58110947)